# Loop Custom Post Type for Single Author

Tags: custom-post-types

I am creating a custom author.php page and on that page I want to have different areas where I can display custom post types (cpt). So in one area I will display the cpt 'blogs', in another area the cpt 'audio' and in another area cpt 'video', etc. -- but all for one author -- say by Albert Einstein, and on his author page.

Ideally, each loop would be conditional so that when there was no cpt, say for 'video' or 'blogs', nothing would display.

I have looked around but cannot find code that works for me. If anyone can help provide code for looping at least one of these cpt's that would be very helpful. Thank you! Here is the code that I am using -- for some reason it is not calling the ctp so no posts are appearing on the page:

```
<?php
    $curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
    query_posts( array(
            'post_type' => array('video'),
            'author' => $author,
            'posts_per_page' => 10 )
        );
?>
```

Comment: Could you post here your current code? What's wrong with it?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Sure! I just edited my question above to include the code. Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using `query_posts()` to create custom queries, for this, use `WP_query()`

You should get what you want with this code.

```
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => array( 'post' ),
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'author'         => $author
    );


    $author_videos = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $author_videos->have_posts() ) : while ( $author_videos->have_posts() ) : $author_videos->the_post(); ?>
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
endif; ?>
```

Comment: Why an empty `else`?

Comment: Hi @Marcos, I had just read about using `WP_query()` instead of `query_posts()` so thanks for correcting me! I tried your code, changing the post_type to 'video' but it is not working for some reason. The page comes up white/blank. I am currently trying to access my error logs to see which line of code it is...

Comment: @s_ha_dum it's just an example in case he would use it. It's easier to delete than write it. ;)

Comment: Are you using this conde on the authors.php file?

Comment: @MarcosRodrigues : welcome. You seem to be new here so I am thinking you don't realize how likely it is that that your code will copied and pasted into who knows how many sites more or less blindly :) It is best to spell out all the _caveats_ explicitly.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Yes, I'm new here. Thanks for the tip, I didn't stop to think about that. I forget that not everybody read or research before use it. I'll write it better and direct to the point. Sorry for the bad english and thanks again.

Comment: @MarcosRodrigues thank you... : yeah, i am saving it in author.php, i am a novice so am easily thrown and probably missing some nuance.

Comment: @MarcosRodrigues Thanks for your edits in your code! My problem now is that something about the array key/value `'author' => $author` inhibits the cpt from being called. While removing the key/value allows the cpt to be called, however not assigned to any author. Does anyone have tips as to what might be causing this? I need to have the cpt assigned to the author.